# javascriptRouter can not take parameters

Tags: javascript, scala, playframework

I am following the Play framework tutorial from here:

http://semisafe.com/coding/2015/03/31/play_basics_templates_and_ajax.html

As instructed, I added the following method in the `Application` controller:

```
def jsRoutes = Action { implicit request =>
  Ok(
    Routes.javascriptRouter("jsRoutes")(
      routes.javascript.Tickets.ticketsAvailable
    )
  )
}
```

I get the following compilation error:

```
play.twirl.api.JavaScript does not take parameters
```

And this line is highlighted:

```
Routes.javascriptRouter("jsRoutes")(
```

But the example in the documentation is very similar to my code(https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.0/ScalaJavascriptRouting). Within it, parameters seem to be passed in a similar manner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [play documentation](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.0/ScalaJavascriptRouting), I gather that you're using the wrong class to create the routes. I think it should be something along the lines of:

```
def jsRoutes = Action { implicit request =>
  Ok(
    JavaScriptReverseRouter("jsRoutes")(
      routes.javascript.Tickets.ticketsAvailable
    )
  ).as(ContentTypes.JAVASCRIPT)
}
```